# After upgrading Python to 3.10, pip installed modules no longer work correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I had been using Python 3.8 for a while and recently updated to 3.10. I made a link for `/usr/bin` to point to the new version and in general things worked fine, until I tried to use a module I had installed via pip a few weeks ago. I noticed that if I ran `python3.8 thescript.py`, it worked fine.

I guessed that, for whatever reason, the global modules installed via pip weren't available to Python 3.10. I just reinstalled them but, as I did, I noticed it wasn't installing because it already existed:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pdfservices-sdk in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.0.1)
```

There's a lot more output, but note it's finding it in 3.8. I tried uninstalling pip and reinstalling it, thinking it would know my current version of Python and use a new directory, but that didn't work.

I also noticed that if I run: `python -m pip`, I get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'
```

But I can do `python3.8 -m pip`. So my pip install is still using 3.8, which I can confirm with `pip --version`.

How do I get pip working with python3.10 again?

I fixed the `distutils.util` issue by doing `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.10-distutils`. I can now run `python -m pip`. But I still have the same issue where when I install, it's doing it to 3.8.

** Another Edit ** I had installed pip via `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`. I know the pip had a script for installing, but that had failed for me. Following a suggestion here, https://github.com/deadsnakes/issues/issues/184, I tried `python get-pip.py --user`, it worked, and I do see pip is now a newer version. When I `pip freeze`, I do *NOT* see the library I was trying to install. I assumed all was well then, but when installing my module (pdfservices-sdk), and it worked for a bit... and then failed on cffi. Partial screen shot:

[image]

Comment: I found a question about the same error [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239829/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-distutils-util), does anything in that link help?

Comment: It did, partially, writing an edit real quick.